# Correspondence between one-parameter subgroups of G and TeG

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading the proof of this theorem from Andreas Arvanitoyeorgos and I cannot get some points in it, highlighted below.

Theorem. The map $\phi \to d\phi_0(1)$ defines a one-to-one correspondence between one-parameter subgroups of $G$ and $T_eG$.

Proof:

Let $v \in T_eG$ and $X^v_g=(dL_g)_e(v)$ be (the value of) the corresponding left-invariant vector field.

We need to find a smooth homomorphism $\phi_v: \mathbb R \to G$.

Let $\phi: I \to G$ be the unique integral curve of $X^v$ such that $\phi(0)=e$ and $d\phi_t=X^v_{\phi(t)}$.

This curve is a homomorphism because if we fix an $s \in I$ such that $s+t \in I$ for all $t \in I$ then the curves

$t \to \phi(s+t)$

and

$t \to \phi(s)\phi(t)$

satisfy the previous equation (the second curve by the left-invariance of $X^v$), and take the common value $\phi(s)$ when $t=0$. By uniqueness of the integral curve then

$\phi(s+t)=\phi(s)\phi(t)$

$(s,t \in I)$

Extend to $\mathbb R$ and define $\phi_v(t)=\phi(t/n)^n$.

The map $v \to \phi_v$ is the inverse of $\phi \to d\phi_0(1)$ and this completes the proof.

***So my questions are these:***

1- We need to find a smooth homomorphism $\phi_v: \mathbb R \to G$. ***(Why?)***

*In particular this part is not clear to me: The map $v \to \phi_v$ is the inverse of $\phi \to d\phi_0(1)$ and this completes the proof.*

2- The map $t \to \phi(s)\phi(t)$ satisfies the integral equation of the vector field by the left-invariance of $X^v$ ***(Why?)***

I see that given the left-invariant vector field we can have 
$dL_{\phi(s)}X^v_{\phi(t)}=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$
and $d(\phi(s)\phi(t))=Y_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$

But I cannot get it that $Y_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$ so that we have 
$d(\phi(s)\phi(t))=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}$ to say that $\phi(s)\phi(t)$ is the same integral curve.

3-**(What 1 in $d\phi_0(1)$ here refer to? Is it n=1?)**

Comment: @marc-van-leeuwen any comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1.$  The correspondence is that there is a bijection from one parameter subgroups and elements of $T_eG$.  A one parameter subgroup is a homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$.  The correspondence takes a one parameter subgroup, $\phi$, such that $\phi(0)=e$ and computes the derivative $d\phi_0(1)\in T_eG$.  The object is to find a $\phi$ such that $d\phi_0(1)=v$ for some given $v\in T_eG$.

$2.$  Call $\psi(t)=\phi(s)\phi(t)$.  Then
$$
d\psi_t=\phi(s)d\phi_t=\phi(s)X^v_{\phi(t)}=X^v_{\phi(s)\phi(t)}=X^v_{\psi(t)}
$$
where the second equality follows by definition of $\phi$.  For the third equality $\phi(s)\in G$ and $X^v$ is invariant under multiplication from group elements, i.e. $gX^v_h=X^v_{gh}$.

$3.$  The number $1$ is just the time you are plugging into the derivative.  Something like if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f'(1)=2$.  Here $\phi$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $G$.  So, it has a derivative at $t=0$.  That derivative is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $T_eG$.  So, $\phi_0(1)$ is that derivative evaluated at $x=1$.  In the above $\phi_0(1)=v$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Points 1 and 3 are still unclear, perhaps you can explain it more. And in point 2 I see that the first equality uses the notion of differential as defined in calculus but in the second we take differential as defined in Lie groups and smooth functions between tangent spaces of manifolds. This is again not obvious to me. Also, for left-invariance in the third equality you are not using the above notation and is rather confusing for me

Comment: @VictorVahidiMotti I have added more.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you have a copy of Andreas Arvanitoyeorgos's? Your notation for left-invariant seems to be different from it. Can you also share your definition of a smooth functions between tangent spaces of manifolds, I mean the definition of the differential of a one-parameter group in its general Lie group sense? In point 2 I see that the first equality uses the notion of differential as defined in calculus but in the second we take differential as defined in Lie groups.

Comment: hi J126 and @user169903 how can it be that $s \in I$ , and $s + t \in I$ for all $t \in I$? i think the point of the demostration is to extend the domain of the integral curve to the full $\mathbb{R}$ but I don't get how. also, in your reply, point 3, I believe that the domain of the differential at a point is a tangent space, correct? so that $1$ should mean $1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ but being $\mathbb{R}$ you can identify its tangent space at a point with $\mathbb{R}$ itself.. what do you think? thanks!!

Comment: @l4teLearner Since an open interval is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, we can just take the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$.  You are correct about identifying tangent spaces.